# WordPress logout after password change "something went wrong" message

Tags: php, wordpress

I use a form and the wp_update_user function to let users change their password in the WordPress frontend. For this i use an ajax function which executes wp_update_user:

```
    /* CHANGE PASSWORD OF USER */
    if ( !empty($pass1 ) && !empty( $pass2 ) ) {
        if ( $pass1 == $pass2 ) {
            wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $userID, 'user_pass' => esc_attr( $pass2 ) ) );
            echo "<div class='message-hub-success'>Passsword changed!</div>";
        } else {
             echo "<div class='message-hub-error'>The passwords you entered do not match.  Your password was not updated.</div>"; 
        }
    }
```

The password change is working as expected. But when the user clicks the logout-link after the password change i get the error "something went wrong" instead of a the logout and the redirect function. My logout link:

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

The something went wrong message is not shown on the page but on a wordpress page with a logout link: [image]

Comment: Can you provide the FULL translation for that error message? Including the link? And paste it in text, rather than a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when you update the password, the user's cookies are cleared (see the documentation for [wp_update_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user)).

Then, during logout, the user's session is not available, which causes the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a workaround for this behaviour like logging out when password is changed or do you have any other solution?

Comment: You might try using the [wp_signon()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function after resetting the password in your AJAX call... you'd use it like so: `wp_signon(['user_login' => 'SomeUsername', 'user_password' => 'TheNewPassword']);` - NOTE that this will have to be run before the `init` hook runs, otherwise the cookies won't be set properly.